# Notice: layouts:head not found in paths: joomla, yoothemes, warp

Tags: joomla, warp, yoothemes

I am in a pickle..I tried to move my joomla site from a sub folder to the root...I've done it before and it worked fine..this time after to the move I got an error:

Notice: layouts:head not found in paths: [/home/p446072r/public_html/beer/templates/yoo_revista/layouts, /home/p446072r/public_html/beer/templates/yoo_revista/warp/systems/joomla/layouts, /home/p446072r/public_html/beer/templates/yoo_revista/warp/layouts] in /home/p446072r/public_html/beer/templates/yoo_revista/warp/helpers/template.php on line 53

I can get into admin

---

Solved

I tried uploading a new copy of the template and it worked..I still have some customizing to do but at least I'm close.

Comment: This is a Yootheme template so should you not be contacting Yootheme?

Comment: problem is they change you just for a single question...i will only as a last resort...